# Cannot access 3rd element in array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I am trying to read in a String over serial and parse the comma separated values form the in string into an array. I seem to be able to do this as I can read in the serial data and log the array out. I have also been able to store first element of the array into another variable. Problem comes when trying to access any other element in the array.

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
String inString="";
PFont font;
int line = 0;

float kph = 0.00;
float distance = 0;


void setup() {
  size(300, 300); //size(1920, 1080);
  printArray(Serial.list());
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);

  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  font = createFont(PFont.list()[6], 20);
  textFont(font);
}

void draw() {
  //The serialEvent controls the display
  logSerialData(inString);
  displayValues();
}  

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {

  // read a byte from the serial port:
  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  // split the string into multiple strings
  // where there is a ","

  String[] items = split(inString, ',');

  kph = float(items[0]);  

  print(inString);
  print(items);
  println(items[2]); //processing falls down here: Error, disabling serialEvent() for COM8 null
  int size = items.length;
  println(size);
}
```

Comment: And what problem you have when accessing to `items[2]`?

Comment: Can you list the results of your print statements?

Comment: Can you print things *before* you use them, for example items.length before you assume there are >= three items? NB 'items[2]' is the third element in the array, not the second.

Comment: @EJP "NB `items[2]` is the third element in the array, not the second." That might be exactly the problem. OP is accessing `items[0]` first and then directly `items[2]` in this code snippet. So most likely he assumes that there are two elements and tries to access the second element with `items[2]`. _In that case, your edit to the title is really wrong._

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It might indeed, but it agrees with his present code. If it's not what he wants, let him fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If the error you are getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: ...
```

It is because your array doesn't have `items[2]`, which is actually the third element in the array.

In Java, arrays start with the position zero.

So the first item is `items[0]`

The second item is at `items[1]`

An example of how you can see the items is

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] items ="a,b".split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("The item in the position "+i+" has the value "+items[i]);
        }

    }
}
```